# Sharepoint 2010 Scroll Bar Problem

Tags: master-page, branding

I'm after introducing a custom menu bar to my master page, unfortunately this has broken scrolling functionality. The code for my custom menu is:

```
    <ul id="Tnav" class="s4-notdlg" scroll="no">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="NavPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ul>
```

When I introduce this the scroll bar no longer reaches far down enough, it's too short by the same height of my custom menu, see below:

[image: Link to scroll bar problem snapshot]

Just looking for a way to fix this, would rather not resort back to using the OOTB top navigation menu, as it doesn't quite meet my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer to this was to declare and adjust the javascript variable `g_wpadderSize` in my masterpage. I had increased the size of my ribbon by putting a custom navigation bar in it and needed to set `g_wpadderSize` to be the extra height in pixels that my navigation bar added to the ribbon.